# Clojure: how to execute shell commands with piping?

Tags: clojure, terminal

I found `(use '[clojure.java.shell :only [sh]])` for executing shell commands with clojure. Now, while `(sh "ls" "-a")` does the job, `(sh "ls" "-a" "| grep" "Doc")` doesn't. What's the trick?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`clojure.java.shell/sh` executes a command (the first argument passed to `sh` function) with specified arguments (the rest of the parameters passed to `sh`).

When you execute:

`(sh "ls" "-a" "| grep" "Doc")`

you ask to execute `ls` with parameters `-a`, `| grep` and `Doc`.

When you type `ls -a | grep Doc` in your terminal then the shell interprets it as executing `ls`, taking its std out and pass it as std in to another process (`grep`) that should be started by the shell.

You could simulate what the shell is doing by starting `ls` as one process, take its std output and then execute `grep` passing output from `ls` as its input.

The simpler solution would be to just ask a `shell` process to execute everything as if it was typed in terminal:

`(sh "bash" "-c" "ls -a | grep Doc")`

It's important to pass `-c` and `ls ...` as separate arguments so bash gets them as a separate parameters. You also need to have the whole command you want to execute as one string (`ls -a | grep Doc`). Otherwise only the first argument after `-c` will be treated as a command. For example this won't do what you would like:

`(sh "bash" "-c" "ls -a" "|" "grep Doc")`

Comment: This is a very well-explained answer, thank you! Now just for pure knowledge, is there a way of doing it by actually sending the output of `(":out (sh "ls" "-a"))` to another `(sh "grep" "Doc")`?

Comment: You can use `:in` option of `sh` to pass the value of `:out` from a previous process. However, using it you loose the feature of streaming of data from one process to another - you will buffer all the output from one process and when it finishes you will pass all its contents to another one. Shell uses pipelines where data is streamed from one process to another without need to buffer everything. You could use `java.lang.Runtime.exec()` and `java.lang.Process.getOutputStream` to obtain the output data from the first process and pass it to the next, but Clojure `sh` doesn't support it.

Comment: You can also take a look at https://github.com/Raynes/conch. It supports pipelines: https://github.com/Raynes/conch#piping